# How transfer Float number due to HTTP GET request?

Tags: java, spring, string, get, floating-point

Could you help me with my issue? I have a back-end on Java Spring Boot and I need to use `GET` request to transfer for example "2300,55". As I understand the `GET` only can transfer Strings and with Long numbers where was no problems yet, but I need to transfer number with comma or with point. How to do this?

I tried to parse it, getting String and parse in try/catch block:

```
...
    @PathVariable("weight") String weight
    try {
        float parsedWeight = Float.parseFloat(weight);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
...
```

And catched

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2300,55"

But if I try it with point in stead of comma  "2300.55" it's persisted OK into database, but it's became just "2300". Database PostgreSQL and column type is `REAL` -> that is `float4` (a single-precision floating-point number (4 bytes))

Comment: How is your entity look like? I think you're using int/long for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And catched java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2300,55"

The issues like having decimal comma instead of point are related to [localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization). If remote sends numbers like `2300,55`, this means it sends numbers in localized form. Generally, this is treated as *Extremely Bad* in network interaction: all data shall be sent between programs in locale-neutral form. Localized forms shall be used only in interaction with humans. So, the suggested way is to fix the remote side that it sent only neutral representations.

But, if you have no influence onto remote side and have to deal with broken forms, try Java [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class methods with setting an expected locale or `LocalDecimalSeparator` separately. For a decimal comma, this is likely some European locale.

(I cannot answer for DB issue.)

Answer (score 0):

(I have not enough reputation to comment) You can simply replace the "," with "." in the string prior to parsing. 
To you second question real is big enough to hold java float so maybe the problem is somewhere in persisting